# mysql error 1054 column not being requested or exists

Tags: mysql, sql-update, field, mysql-error-1054

I have a table where I am attempting to update columns name, pw and accessed depending on there email.
 The query is :

```
Update everyone set name="name", pw="pass", accessed=CURDATE() where email="email";
```

The table has therefore these column names.

However it throws the 1054 error claiming column user does not exist. Any advice?
Also this error only seems to appear when attempting update.

Thanks in advance

Comment: provide your table struture ....

Comment: Your query does not reference a column `user`.  Are there any triggers on update?  `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS WHERE EVENT_OBJECT_SCHEMA = DATABASE() AND EVENT_OBJECT_TABLE = 'everyone' AND EVENT_MANIPULATION = 'UPDATE'`?

Comment: You have a column called 'user'?

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS :

Update `everyone` set `name`="name", `pw`="pass", `accessed`=CURDATE() where `email`="email";